# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method get() on null object

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the next Groovy code which I try to run in Jenkins Pipeline:

```
@Grab('io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-core:1.0.3')

import static groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder.configure

def astros = configure {
    request.uri = 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json'
}.get()

println "There are ${astros.number} astronauts in space right now."

astros.people.each { p->
    println " - ${p.name} (${p.craft})"
}
```

But everytime I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method get() on null object` error.

When I run it from my desktop, everything works as expected:

```
There are 6 astronauts in space right now.
```

In Jenkins:

```
There are null astronauts in space right now.
```

Debug output:

```
<groovyx.net.http.UriBuilder$Basic@4bc2413c scheme=http port=-1 host=api.open-notify.org path=/astros.json query=[:] fragment=null userInfo=null parent=groovyx.net.http.UriBuilder$ThreadSafe@69c6847a useRawValues=null>
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Double check the version of Groovy being used as well as any differences between your classpath in both situations.

Comment: Paths are identical, versions of groovy also.

Answer (score 0):

object.get() will give an NullPointerException if the object is null, so you need to check if the object is null or not before you call any method on it. so, an alternative could to check if `astros != null` and then call `.get()` within the if-block.

Comment: But out of jenkins this works fine. This code was in official docs of httpbuilder-ng. I think Jenkins handles this code incorrectly to some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the null issue inside your code as follows (Use null safe operator and groovy truth concept.)

```
@Grab('io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-core:1.0.3')

import static groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder.configure
def astros = configure {
    request.uri = 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json'
}?.get() // added null safe operator here (will handle null pointer exception)

println "There are ${astros?.number} astronauts in space right now."
//iterate if astros value exists.
if(astros){
  astros.people.each { p->
    println " - ${p.name} (${p.craft})"
  }
}
```

// As you are having json, you need to parse that as follows.

```
  def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
  def result = slurper.parseText(astros)
  println result
  println result?.number
```

Comment: But it doesn't solve issue. Here is an output from GroovyConsole on my desktop: There are 6 astronauts in space right now and here is from Jenkins: There are null astronauts in space right now. I still get null, I am trying to understand why I get null instead of correct result in Jenkins.

Comment: You need to check that, why you are having null astronauts? debug to get that value then.

Comment: <groovyx.net.http.UriBuilder$Basic@4bc2413c scheme=http port=-1 host=api.open-notify.org path=/astros.json query=[:] fragment=null userInfo=null parent=groovyx.net.http.UriBuilder$ThreadSafe@69c6847a useRawValues=null>

Comment: @user54 : You need to parse json if your call is fine, do the changes as I have added in my answer.

Comment: Issue doesn't lie in JSON, if run GET request to any URL, result will be the same regarding null object.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you created a shared library and is trying to use this in a pipeline?

I have the same problem at the moment, I think it might be a limitation of the Groovy interpreter on Jenkins, similar to how the each loop didn't work [until some time ago](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481).

I've resorted to using this version of [http-builder](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder) to circumvent that for now. I'll update this if I find a proper solution (please also post an answer if you find anything).

Comment: The single workable solution for me, for now, is curl usage under sh DSL directive. And that vers of HTTP builder is very old and it doesn't have a PATCH method and some other things which I need which are available in ng version of builder.

Answer (score -2):

if you facing "**java.lang.nullpointerexception cannot invoke**" then try to initialize every element of object_array with new class() like:

```
Result[] s=new Result[3];

s[0]=new Result();
s[1]=new Result();
s[2]=new Result();
```

Example:

```
class hybrid1
    {
    public static void main(String arg[]) 
        {
        Result[] s;
        s=new Result[3];
        //s[0]=new Result();
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
            s[i]=new Result();
            s[i].getroll(101);
            s[i].getmarks(88.36F,78.65F);
            s[i].display();
            }
        
        /*Result s1;
        s1=new Result();
        s1.getroll(101);
        s1.getmarks(58,69);
        s1.display();*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is about Groovy code. You gave an answer in Java, about a completely different case.